# Disable type annotation for specific types with Json.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

In the process of moving away from `$type` annotations (in order to make the data language-independent), I'm having some issues understanding the priority of the various `TypeNameHandling` annotations and type contract.

During the transiton, both the new types and old types will be contained in the same files. Therefore the file must contain the type annotations on all but the new types (`ISettings` implementations).

I've tried to reproduce my problem with the following minimum example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

namespace jsontest
{
    // I can't touch this class, even to add annotations
    // (in practice there are too many classes to update)
    interface IDoNotTouchThis {}
    class DoNotTouchThisClass : IDoNotTouchThis {
        public IMustHaveType MustHaveType => new HasType();
    }

    // This is the old data. It must have type annotations to be deserialized.
    interface IMustHaveType {}
    class HasType : IMustHaveType {}

    // This is the new data. It must not have type annotations.
    // There is a `JsonConverter` to figure out the types according to the fields.
    interface ISettings {}
    class SettingsFoo: ISettings {
        public String Foo => "NotImportant";
    }
    class SettingsBar: ISettings {
        public String Bar => "NotImportant";
        public ISettings SubSettings => new SettingsFoo();
    }

    // This is the top-level class of the data.
    class AllSettings {
        public IDoNotTouchThis MustHaveType => new DoNotTouchThisClass();

        public ISettings MustNotHaveType => new SettingsFoo();

        [JsonProperty(ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None)] // This helps, but isn't enough
        public IReadOnlyList<ISettings> MustNotHaveTypeEither => new List<ISettings> {
            new SettingsFoo(),
            new SettingsBar(),
        };
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Program.Serialize(new AllSettings()));
        }

        private static JsonSerializerSettings SerializeSettings { get; }
            = new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                // For backward compatibility:
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
                TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling = TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling.Full,
                ContractResolver = new JsonConverterContractResolver(),
            };

        private static string Serialize<T>(T o)
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                o,
                Formatting.Indented,
                Program.SerializeSettings);
        }
    }

    public class JsonConverterContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
        {
            JsonContract contract = base.CreateContract(objectType);

            // Here I'm hopping to disable type annotations for all `ISettings` instances.
            if (objectType == typeof(ISettings)
                || (objectType.IsClass && objectType.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i == typeof(ISettings)))
                || (objectType == typeof(IReadOnlyList<ISettings>))
                || (objectType == typeof(List<ISettings>)))
            {
                if (contract is JsonContainerContract objectContract)
                {
                    objectContract.ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None;
                }
            }

            return contract;
        }
    }
}
```

([.NET Fiddle link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tZUv1X))

With this example, we're getting the following:

```json
{
   // Not necessary, but doesn't hurt:
  "$type": "jsontest.AllSettings, pzyc3cmg.exe, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
  "MustHaveType": {
    "$type": "jsontest.DoNotTouchThisClass, pzyc3cmg.exe, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
    "MustHaveType": {
      "$type": "jsontest.HasType, pzyc3cmg.exe, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
    }
  },
  "MustNotHaveType": {
    "$type": "jsontest.SettingsFoo, pzyc3cmg.exe, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
    "Foo": "NotImportant"
  },
  "MustNotHaveTypeEither": {
    "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[jsontest.ISettings, pzyc3cmg.exe, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
    "$values": [
      {
        "Foo": "NotImportant"
      },
      {
        "Bar": "NotImportant",
        "SubSettings": {
          "Foo": "NotImportant"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

instead of

```json
{
   // Not necessary, but doesn't hurt:
  "$type": "jsontest.AllSettings, pzyc3cmg.exe, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
  "MustHaveType": {
    "$type": "jsontest.DoNotTouchThisClass, pzyc3cmg.exe, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
    "MustHaveType": {
      "$type": "jsontest.HasType, pzyc3cmg.exe, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
    }
  },
  "MustNotHaveType": {
    "Foo": "NotImportant"
  },
  "MustNotHaveTypeEither": [
    {
      "Foo": "NotImportant"
    },
    {
      "Bar": "NotImportant",
      "SubSettings": {
        "Foo": "NotImportant"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried applying `TypeNameHandling`/`ItemTypeNameHandling` annotations at different places without success. Is the format I'm looking for possible with Json.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

I was able to find a way to dynamically set `TypeNameHandling` on `JsonObjectContract` properties in `CreateContract` method, which seems to have solved the issue. Check out .Net fiddler [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GvNkt4):

```
public class JsonConverterContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
    {
        JsonContract contract = base.CreateContract(objectType);

        if (contract is JsonObjectContract)
        {
            var objectContract = contract as JsonObjectContract;
            foreach (var property in objectContract.Properties)
            {
                var propertyType = property.PropertyType;
                if (IsTypeOfISettings(propertyType))
                {
                    // setting type name handling on property level
                    property.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None;
                }
            }
        }

        // Here I'm hopping to disable type annotations for all `ISettings` instances.
        if (IsTypeOfISettings(objectType))
        {
            if (contract is JsonContainerContract objectContract)
            {
                objectContract.ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None;
            }
        }

        return contract;
    }

    private bool IsTypeOfISettings(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(ISettings)
                || (objectType.IsClass && objectType.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i == typeof(ISettings)))
                || (objectType == typeof(IReadOnlyList<ISettings>))
                || (objectType == typeof(List<ISettings>))
                || (objectType == typeof(Dictionary<string, ISettings>));
    }
}
```

**Original answer:**

I believe so, take a look at this updated [.NET fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/b5c8vE) Only change I made in this fiddle was replace `ItemTypeNameHandling` with `TypeNameHandling` in `AllSettings` class properties and it worked! I got inspiration by looking at internal working of Newtonsoft.Json, specifically [serializer writer](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/666d9760719e5ec5b2a50046f7dbd6a1267c01c6/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs#L997).

```
class AllSettings {
    public IDoNotTouchThis MustHaveType => new DoNotTouchThisClass();

    [JsonProperty(TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None)]
    public ISettings MustNotHaveType => new SettingsFoo();

    [JsonProperty(TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None)]
    public IReadOnlyList<ISettings> MustNotHaveTypeEither => new List<ISettings> {
        new SettingsFoo(),
        new SettingsBar(),
    };
}
```

Result looks like:

```
{
  "$type": "jsontest.AllSettings, tciypvk5.exe, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
  "MustHaveType": {
    "$type": "jsontest.DoNotTouchThisClass, tciypvk5.exe, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
    "MustHaveType": {
      "$type": "jsontest.HasType, tciypvk5.exe, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
    }
  },
  "MustNotHaveType": {
    "Foo": "NotImportant"
  },
  "MustNotHaveTypeEither": [
    {
      "Foo": "NotImportant"
    },
    {
      "Bar": "NotImportant",
      "SubSettings": {
        "Foo": "NotImportant"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution is very fragile. It would require me to add annotation to many places and add all possible types the settings belong to in the contract. Eg. this is incorrect: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GvNkt4.

Comment: Ah I see, let me see if there is anything else you could leverage. But adding attribute to property or class would work for you right? Or you cannot update existing classes at all?

Comment: Adding an attribute to all `ISettings` implementations would work, but not to all properties of type `ISettings` and derivatives.

Comment: `objectContract.Properties` + `property.TypeNameHandling` seems to have been the missing piece of the puzzle. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked! Reverse engineering always does, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Weirdly, I could only get anything working if I turned it on it's head and disabled type serialization by default, then enabled it on the specific (old) types. That's not ideal in your case because it means you'd need to list all the old types in the resolver which I guess is a lot of work.

```
private static JsonSerializerSettings SerializeSettings { get; }
    = new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        // Disable by default
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None,
        TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling = TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling.Full,
        ContractResolver = new JsonConverterContractResolver(),
    };

public class JsonConverterContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
    {
        JsonContract contract = base.CreateContract(objectType);

        if (contract is JsonContainerContract objectContract)
        {            
          // enable on old types
          if (typeof(IDoNotTouchThis).IsAssignableFrom(objectType))
          {
            objectContract.ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All;
          }
        }

        return contract;
    }
}
```

That produces this output, is that what you need?

```
{
  "MustNotHaveType": {
    "Foo": "NotImportant"
  },
  "MustHaveType": {
    "MustHaveType": {
      "$type": "jsontest.HasType, a0tq5y51.exe, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
    }
  },
  "MustNotHaveTypeEither": [
    {
      "Foo": "NotImportant"
    },
    {
      "Bar": "NotImportant",
      "SubSettings": {
        "Foo": "NotImportant"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

fiddle:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/ckDb6Z

Comment: “list all the old types” is definitely not doable, so I though I could get around that by [inverting the condition](https://dotnetfiddle.net/V1ln5J). But then again, the first `MustNotHaveType` has a type annotation even though it's assignable to `ISettings`.

Comment: It seems that `ItemTypeNameHandling` doesn't apply to an object, but to the parent object for _all_ its name/value pairs (which Json.NET seems to call item).